# Trying to loop through an array of objects to populate arrays with data in objects

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I'm writing a node script to gather a bunch of file names and locations over several hard drives. The issue is that I'm trying to dial into the "dirs" array of objects with a loop so instead of having to code for dirs[i].tv, dirs[i].movies, dirs[i].images, etc for each object in the array I'll have an array of ["tv", "movies", "images, "etc"] that's looped through. I ended up with something like "dirs[i].n" with "n" being a variable defined by the loop, but that's the issue that isn't working. Since "n" isn't defined in the object the script is returning an error

Below is the code I'm working with

```
var dirs = [
    {
        name: "C",
        loc: "C:/",
        tv: undefined,
        movies: undefined,
        images: "Users/'Master William'/Pictures/",
        music: undefined,
        torrents: undefined,
        porn: undefined
    },
    {
        name: "D",
        loc: "D:/",
        tv: "Video/TV/",
        movies: "Video/Movies/",
        images: "images/pics/",
        music: "Music/",
        torrents: "Torrents/",
        porn: undefined
    },
    {
        name: "I",
        loc: "I:/",
        tv: "Users/heliu/Videos/TV/",
        movies: "Users/heliu/Videos/Movies/",
        images: "Users/heliu/Desktop/Will/Pics/",
        music: "Users/heliu/Music/",
        torrents: undefined,
        porn: "Users/heliu/Videos/Pr0n/"
    },
    {
        name: "J",
        loc: "J:/",
        tv: "Video/TV/",
        movies: "Video/Movies/",
        images: "Pics",
        music: "Tunes/",
        torrents: undefined,
        porn: "Pornography/"
    }
]

const fs = require("fs");
var tvArr = [];
var moviesArr = [];
var imagesArr = [];
var musicArr = [];
var torrentsArr = [];
var pornArr = [];
var mediaArr = ["tv", "movies", "images", "music", "torrents", "porn"];
var arrArr = [tvArr, moviesArr, imagesArr, musicArr, torrentsArr, pornArr];


for( var i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++){
    let o = dirs[i].loc;
    for( var j = 0; j < mediaArr.length; j++){
        let n = mediaArr[j];
        if(dirs[i].n !== undefined){
            let x = dirs[i].loc+dirs[i].n;
            fs.readdirSync(x).forEach(file => {
                arrArr[j].push(file);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Trying to find a better way to do it?

Comment: `n` is a string, right? And then you try to access the property using `dirs[i].n`? I think you need to do `dirs[i][n]` then.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the media array to

`var mediaArr = [dirs[i].tv, dirs[i].movies, dirs[i].images, etc..]`

and scoped it within the loop so it could identify "i"